# I just started learning SQL and I couldn't do the query, can you help me?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a field in the sql query that I can't do. First of all, a new column must be added to the table below. The value of this column needs to be percent complete, so it's a percentage value. So for example, there are 7 values from Cupboard=1 shelves. Where IsCounted is here, 3 of them are counted. In other words, those with Cupboard = 1 should write the percentage value of 3/7 as the value in the new column to be created. If the IsCounted of the others is 0, it will write zero percent. How can I do this?

My Sql Code:

```sql
SELECT a.RegionName,
       a.Cupboard,
       a.Shelf,
       (CASE WHEN ToplamSayım > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsCounted
FROM (SELECT p.RegionName,
             r.Shelf,
             r.Cupboard,
             (SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductCountingNew
              WHERE RegionCupboardShelfTypeId = r.Id) AS ToplamSayım
      FROM FAZIKI.dbo.DF_PMRegionType p
          JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_PMRegionCupboardShelfType r ON p.Id = r.RegionTypeId
      WHERE p.WarehouseId = 45) a
ORDER BY a.RegionName;
```

The result is as in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a windowed `AVG` should do the trick, although it's not entirely clear what the partitioning column should be.

The `SELECT COUNT` can be simplified to an `EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT a.RegionName,
       a.Cupboard,
       a.Shelf,
       a.IsCounted,
       AVG(a.IsCounted * 1.0) OVER (PARTITION BY a.RegionName, a.Cupboard) Percentage
FROM (
      SELECT p.RegionName,
             r.Shelf,
             r.Cupboard,
             CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM FAZIKI.dbo.PM_ProductCountingNew pcn
                 WHERE pcn.RegionCupboardShelfTypeId = r.Id
             ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsCounted
      FROM FAZIKI.dbo.DF_PMRegionType p
          JOIN FAZIKI.dbo.DF_PMRegionCupboardShelfType r ON p.Id = r.RegionTypeId
      WHERE p.WarehouseId = 45
) a
ORDER BY a.RegionName;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. I didn't know how to do it but you did it for me. Again Thank you